# Set ReadOnly for ng2-tag-input in angular

Tags: angular, ng2-tag-input

I have implemented tag input. I need to set tag-input as readonly.

```
<tag-input  disabled  readonly="true" 
    (onSelect)="onSelect($event)" secondaryPlaceholder="">
</tag-input>
```

The above code is not working, `[readonly]="true"` also not working.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in tag-input field:

```
[readonly]="true"
```